# pandas remove parentheses and the inside stuff in a string keep one space inside it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to remove parentheses and the inside stuff in a string in pandas framework but I want to keep one space if the "()" inside the string.

e.g.

```
 (.)y(...)rfer  --> y rfer
 a(...)ewq()   --> a ewq
```

my code:

```
  df['a_id'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('\(.*\)', ' '))
```

does not work.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using `regex`

```
df.xx.str.replace('\([^\)]*\)',' ')
Out[1249]: 
0     y rfer
1     a ewq 
Name: xx, dtype: object
```